# Get program path in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I get the absolute path of program I'm running?

Comment: Is your code in the exe or an a .dll assembly?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For that you can use the [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.aspx) object.

Startup path, just the folder, use [Application.StartupPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)

```
Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()
```

Full .exe path, including the program.exe name on the end:, use [Application.ExecutablePath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx)

```
Dim exePath As String = Application.ExecutablePath()
```

Comment: does not allow me application. Is this in a namespace that I need to import? if so which?

Comment: Am I to understand `StartupPath()` would return something like `"C:\testfolder\"` and `ExecutablePath()` would return `"C:\testfolder\test.exe"`

Answer (score 24):

Try this: `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo.directorypath.aspx)

This is using the `My` feature of VB.NET. This particular property is available for all non-web project types, since .NET Framework 2.0, including Console Apps as you require.

As long as you trust Microsoft to continue to keep this working correctly for all the above project types, this is simpler to use than accessing the other "more direct" solutions.

```
Dim appPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

Comment: @ColeJohnson I have asked on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144565/147650) to clarify this.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use:

```
Dim strPath As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 4):

For a console application you can use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` as long as the call is made within the code of the console app itself, if you call this from within another dll or plugin this will return the location of that DLL and not the executable.

Answer (score 3):

You can get path by this code

```
Dim CurDir as string = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

Answer (score 1):

If the path is a drive, a slash will also appear in the path, and this time the use will cause problems. To unify, the best solution is the following command.

```
        Dim FileName As String = "MyFileName"
    Dim MyPath1 As String = Application.StartupPath().TrimEnd("\") & "\" & FileName
    Dim MyPath2 As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.TrimEnd("\") & "\" & FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Your Own application Path

Dim myPathsValues As String

```
    TextBox1.Text = Application.StartupPath
    TextBox2.Text = Len(Application.StartupPath)
    TextBox3.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Application.StartupPath, 10)
    myPathsValues = Val(TextBox2.Text) - 9
    TextBox4.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(Application.StartupPath, myPathsValues) & "Reports"
```

Answer (score -3):

I use:

```
Imports System.IO
Dim strPath as String=Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
```

Comment: This returns the current directory, which is often not where the program is.