# Executable directory where application is running from?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, executable, desktop-application

I need to get the path (not the executable) where my application is running from:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()
```

When I run the above statement with & "/images/image.jpg" on my local machine it works fine but when I install the application on another machine it says it cannot find the file and there is a lot of extra path information some.

I just need the directory of where the app is running.  I am coding in VB.NET with Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: dont know much about vs 2008 but when you do a dirinfo dont you get the dirinfo from where the app. is running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get programs path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216141/get-programs-path)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Dim strPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( _
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
```

Taken from [HOW TO: Determine the Executing Application's Path (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)

Comment: strPath contains **file**:\\c:\\xxxxxx

Comment: This is not safe, for example when it is being used to open config file it causes `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: URI formats are not supported`

Comment: This link is out of date :(.

Answer (score 41):

This is the first post on google so I thought I'd post different ways that are available and how they compare.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to create a table here, so it's an image.  The code for each is below the image using fully qualified names.

[image]

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

Environment.CurrentDirectory

System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.CodeBase

New System.UriBuilder(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.CodeBase)

Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString((New System.UriBuilder(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.CodeBase).Path)))

Uri.UnescapeDataString((New System.UriBuilder(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.CodeBase).Path))
```

---
**Edit October 18, 2021:**

Sigh... None of the above work if using net5.0 or net6.0 and publishing app as single-file bundle. Best I got now is:

```cs
// This will give you the directory but not the assembly
string basedir = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
// Before you package the app as a single file bundle, you will get the dll.  
// But after you publish it, you'll get the exe. 
string pathToExecutable = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0].Replace(".dll", ".exe");
```

Comment: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()
Works good also in console/service application!

Answer (score 15):

I needed to know this and came here, before I remembered the Environment class.

In case anyone else had this issue, just use this: `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Example:

```
Dim dataDirectory As String = String.Format("{0}\Data\", Environment.CurrentDirectory)
```

When run from Visual Studio in debug mode yeilds:

```
C:\Development\solution folder\application folder\bin\debug
```

This is the exact behaviour I needed, and its simple and straightforward enough.

Comment: Smallest, easiest solution, with formatting! +1, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this help to make the application truly portable, by keeping the settings file in the root path of the application. Thanks for the simple solution!

Comment: @vr_driver This is bad. For portable the executable file's parent directory should be used, not the current directory, which can be different from the former. For example if a script running in `%windir%` calls the program using an absolute path it will look for ` %windir%\data\ ` and that is bad.

Comment: @jason-alls: Your example output is not 100% correct. With your code you get `C:\Development\solution folder\application folder\bin\debug\DATA` because you add it to your value from `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me.  All the Application properties were returning .Net framework -based results, this returned the actual directory my app is running in.

Comment: Digging old posts and found this! Thanks a lot, saved my day!

Answer (score 14):

```
Dim P As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
P = New Uri(P).LocalPath
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the static [StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property of the Application class.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetParentDirectory(GetType(MyClass).Assembly.Location), "Images\image.jpg")
```

Comment: There are pitfalls to this approach as the assembly does not necessarily reside in the same directory as the executing assembly.