# How do can I get the current working directory inside a Setup/Installation project

Tags: vb.net, add-in, visual-sourcesafe

I am makeing add-in application in vb.net
and also making setup for that, but i need some help in instller.vb class file

i want to copy TestAddIn.addin file to client location,and this is added with setup file
how can i do code in installer file that it copy to client machine?

target path :

```
Dim addinTargetPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2008\Addins")
```

source path:

```
dim addinsourcePath As String =....................???????????
```

what to write in source path that give me current working directory?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the question [executable directory where application is running from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593458/executable-directory-where-application-is-running-from); the answer provided by Justin Niessner is a very good solution and will return the path of the currently executing application

The returned string will have the format "Path:\Directory" so you will have to trim the first 6 characters to use it as a path string in your program.  This is how I used it in one of my programs

```
strPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
i = strPath.Count
strPath = strPath.Substring(6, i - 6)
```

Answer (score -2):

To get the current working directory:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx

Comment: this code give me Path Of windows32 directory, i want the path where my setup is placed?