# Get full path to .exe file if only a subfolder path to it is given

Tags: vb.net, path

I have to find the `rscript.exe` that exists in a folder called bin but I do not have the full reference to this folder.

Full Reference would be:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin
```

but I do not know the version part beforehand. So I must go to

`C:\Program Files\R` and search the subfolders for the `rscript.exe` and recieve the full path to it.

I have already searched but all I could find was how to find out the path of the [running application via reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593458/executable-directory-where-application-is-running-from) and tried out to rewrite the code without any solution. Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories) method with the `searchPattern` argument and loop throught the subdirectories:

```
Dim rootPath As String = "C:\Program Files\R"

If Directory.Exists(rootPath) Then
    Dim currPath As String

    For Each subFolder As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath, "R-*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        currPath = IO.Path.Combine(subFolder, "bin", "rscript.exe")

        If IO.File.Exists(currPath) Then
            MessageBox.Show("File found at " & currPath)
        End If
    Next
End If
```