# Is there a possible way to open a file in visual basic by just putting the name of the drive?

Tags: vb.net, file, inno-setup

Recently I made an application that has lots of PDF files in it and I made a setup for it using Inno Setup Compiler. In the setup, I allowed people to change where they want to install the app. For opening my PDF files, I used: `system.diagnostics.process.start("My pdf.pdf")`

My problem is that in the code above, I put drive "C:" and when my user changed the install directory to drive "D:" the pdf's did not work and the error showed that "Cannot find the specific file". My question is that is there a way to just put the name of "computer" or "a drive" in the code above, not the specific name of the pdf, and let the computer find the file itself?

Comment: Let the computer find it itself? How does it know that you want `My pdf.pdf` and not `Copy of personal finances (3).xlsx.docx`? (https://www.xkcd.com/1459/)

Comment: Of course not. You might have more than one file with the same name in different folders. You might have hundreds of thousands of folders. You need a way to keep track of where the user chose to put the files - or else, don't allow the users to choose.

Comment: Or if that setup is uninstallable with the registry settings creation allowed (which is *by default*), you can get the path the user selected in that setup from registry.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking for an opposite of what you actually want to achieve.

I assume you are installing files with *known names*. What you *do not know* is the directory of the files.

From your description I assume that your actual code is like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\My pdf.pdf")
```

But when the user chooses a different location (directory) for your application, the above code with a hard-coded absolute path fails.

If your application installs to the same directory as the PDFs, just use a relative path (in this case just a file name without any path). It makes an operating system look to the current working directory, which will typically be an application directory.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("My pdf.pdf")
```

Or to make it more reliable, make it explicitly look to the application directory. For that use [`Application.StartupPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "My pdf.pdf"))
```

See also [Get program path in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2216141/850848)