# Relative path for a xls file in Windows Form application vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, relative-path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ukyT.png)I am new to VB.Net and I am stuck in using the relative path for a xls file in vb.Net. I tried using resource file method but in vain. Can somebody please help me.

I have a VB.NET **Windows Form application** for which I am using an Excel file as my DB. In my local system I can access that file by giving the full path. But if I have to run it on another system I need a relative path to the excel file.

How can I access an Excel file by giving its relative path in my VB.NET application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216141/get-programs-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the following method, use Combine which will add the directory separator for you and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory instead of Application.StartUpPath because it is not available when moving code to a class project. Of course the code sample below assumes the file is in the app folder, if in another location let us know.

```
Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyFileName.xls")
If IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
    ' do work
End If
```

Example

```
Dim Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes;")
Builder.DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Explanaation_notes.xls")
Dim con As New OleDbConnection(Builder.ConnectionString)
```

Here is a modified example to go with your last question for "Files" folder

```
Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Files", "Explanaation_notes.xls")
If IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
    Dim Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
    Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes;")
    Builder.DataSource = fileName
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(Builder.ConnectionString)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Karen.I tried the above method but when I use the string in my data source in oledb function I get an error. When I debug I see that the data source has the value "filename.XLS".I have added my excel sheet in the bin/debug folder. Can you please help me.
[This is the error I am getting][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz1WO.png

Comment: I added an example to the answer from yesterday that uses a component to create the connection string properly :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Karen, it works perfectly :) One last question,I was wondering, if I had a separate folder called FILES and stored all my excel files there, then is it possible to call the excel file from the folder FILES?

Comment: I revised my reply to show how to reference a folder beneath the project folder e.g. C:\SomeFolder\Files\Explanaation_notes.xls

Comment: Thanks a lot Karen :)