# How to send a file via FTP that is in the same folder as my program?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, upload

I found a tutorial on the internet where the guy shows how to create a complete way that send files via FTP to the server, the question is: How to send a file via FTP that is in the same program folder? No need to fill in the fields, just a button to send.

**Here is the Form**

[image]

**Here is the Code of this Form**

```
Private Sub BT_Upload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_Upload.Click
    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(
        txtFile.Text, txtServer.Text & ofdBrowser.SafeFileName,
        txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If ofdBrowser.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        txtFile.Text = ofdBrowser.FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the path with [`Application.StartupPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim myFile As String = "myFile.txt"
Dim fullFilePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, myFile)
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(fullFilePath, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Get program path in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2216141/850848)

```
Dim progPath As String = 
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath())
Dim filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(progPath, txtFile.Text)

My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(filePath, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path easily and use it like below :

```
Private Sub BT_Upload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_Upload.Click
    Dim _filePath As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location) & "\" & txtFile.Text
    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(
        _filePath, txtServer.Text & ofdBrowser.SafeFileName,
        txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text)
End Sub
```